# Show subcontent with fake pages in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am working on a WordPress theme that was made by someone before me. The website is for a band, and if you want to see the releases of the band the URL is in this format:
www.domain.com/band/[bandname]/releases/

I am now trying to make a subsection with details of each release. The links from the overview of releases now works, and when the users click the link they get to the URL:
www.domain.com/band/releases/[name-of-release]

The releases are custom post types created with "More Types", and the child content are made with fake pages. A template seems to be loaded based on the slug/page the user is visiting. This is for the 'releases' page:

```
if ($current == 'releases') {
        get_template_part( 'single', 'band-releases' );
    }
```

I have made a template for showing an individual release as well, but how can I get template based on its slug as it will be dynamic (several releases)?

Comment: It's hard to tell, without looking at the setup. Are releases a custom post type? or a category of posts? You should take a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ Depending of what they are, you should only need to name your template a specific way for WP to know to use it (eg. single-releases.php).

Comment: @coopersita It's a custom post type. Looked at the link, but can't say I found what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a custom post type, the template that displays the individual releases (www.domain.com/releases/[name-of-release]) is single.php.

The template single.php will also be used to display all individual posts. If you want a template that is just for the releases, create a file called single-releases.php (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post).

If you name your templates properly, WP will know which template goes with which content.

Comment: So in my example, the `/releases/[name-of-release]` will go to single-releases.php? Or single.php?

Comment: It will go to single-releases.php, and if that doesn't exits, it will look for single.php, and if that doesn't exist, it will go to index.php (template hierarchy in action).

Comment: I was a little wrong. It should be `/band/[bandname]/releases/[name-of-release]`. Still the same? Even though there is a template called single-band.php as well? single-band-releases.php turns up if I go to `/band/[bandname]/releases/`, but not when I go to `/band/releases/[name-of-release]`.

Comment: You seem to have a complicated setup. I would simply do some tests. Create single-releases.php, and see if that template is being used, or you could try using a plugin: https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/reveal-template/

Comment: It seems like all child content of `/band/` uses `single-band.php`. And in that file again you find the code I wrote in my question. All child content of the custom post type "releases" are made with fake pages.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just not sure how your post types are set up. There must be a way to have a template just for those posts. Did you try creating a single-releases.php? Without understanding how your post types are set up, it will be imposible to figure it out.

Comment: Ok. I am using "More Types" plugin to set them up. But is there a way to create a template file with wildcard values? Like single-band-[bandname]-releases.php